# Do Anylogic models with external dependencies that need "write" permission runnable on the (Anylogic) public cloud?

Tags: java, anylogic, or-tools, access-denied, public-cloud

I am using Google OR-Tools as an external dependency in an Anylogic model. The model runs on the Anylogic desktop version. However, after I upload my code on the (Anylogic) public cloud, I get this error:

"Error during model startup:
access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/run/executor/disk0/u7d2c1f9f/jars/lib/ortools-linux-x86-64-9.5.2237.jar" "write")"

I encountered this problem also when using other external packages such as PowSyBl with Anylogic:

"access denied("java.io.FilePermission" "/var/run/executor/disk1/u5d6d89cc/home/.itools" "write")"

It seems that it is required to have "write" permission for all directories hardcoded in an external package, but as far as I know, it is not possible to give those permissions in the public version of AnyLogic Cloud. What should I do to resolve the error and run it on the public cloud?

Comment: Afaik the public AL cloud blocks any Internet access queries for "Guest" users and those without an active cloud subscription. Does it work when you use a cloud-subscribed account?

Comment: No, it does not. Access can only be provided in the private cloud, where one can install it onsite and host manually, so there's a way to provide the permissions there.
However, my question is mainly that "is there a way that I hinder external packages from asking for such access so they can still do their job on the public cloud?"